# Select Records which have distance of 5km or greater between them

Tags: mysql

I am working on a location app and i need to get all locations from my Mysql Location table which have a 5km distance between them.

For Ex location table have below entries:

```
  id     Latitude       Longitude
  1     22.7499180     75.8950577
  2     22.7498474     75.8950653
  3     22.7498035     75.8950424
  4     22.7497787     75.8950729
  5     22.7498245     75.8950806
  6     22.7497902     75.8950272
  7     22.7497864     75.8950424
  8     22.7497768     75.8950500
  9     22.7497864     75.8950577
  10    22.7497921     75.8950653
  11    22.7497597     75.8950653
  12    22.7498283     75.8950653
  13    22.7497978     75.8950577
```

So from above table how i need to fetch results something like this

```
  id     Latitude       Longitude   Distance (>=5Km)
  1     22.7499180     75.8950577     --
  4     22.7497787     75.8950729    6km (From lat long of id 1)
  8     22.7497768     75.8950500    8km (From lat long of id 4)
  11    22.7497597     75.8950653    6km (From lat long of id 8)
  13    22.7497978     75.8950577    10km (From lat long of id 11)
```

I searched a lot to get such results but i got query only to get result on basis of some fixed lat/long or a fixed radius. Please help with Mysql query if possible.

**Edit**  (from OP's comment)

I need is to calculate distance from last selected value... For Ex. Start from Record 1. distance of 1 is compared with record 2 it is < 5km, compared with record 3 also < 5km ,when compared with 4 its distance is > 5km so we keep it in list THAN NEXT RECORD WILL BE COMPARED WITH RECORD 4. so distance of 4 will be compared with 5 and if record 5 have distance > 5km from 4 next comparison is done with record 5 as reference.

Comment: Hint: this is one of the places a Cartesian product or CROSS JOIN actually can be used.

Comment: @Namphibian Thanks for the hint.. can you please help me with query which generate my desired results.

Comment: @Namphibian I tried everything... Can you please help me with Mysql query for such result ?

Comment: So your intent is, starting at record 1, find the point (if any) among the remaining records that is the *most* distant from *no less* than 5KM?, and then repeat that for each discovered record?

Comment: This task is better done in PHP/Perl/Java/etc than in MySQL, even using a Stored Procedure with a Cursor.

Comment: @DavidW Exactly, You are right...

Comment: @RickJames My server side language is PHP and i am using codeigniter framework.. it would be great help if you provide me solution in PHP too..

Comment: "among the remaining records" is still ambiguous.  After finding the first item (and using your example), there are 12 "remaining rows".  After getting ids 1 and 4, there are 11 "remaining", namely 2,3, and 5 thru 11.  _Or_  "When walking through the table, consider only the ones not yet touched".  In that case, after getting ids 1 and 4, only 7 are "remaining", namely #5 thru #11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No stored procedure, just pure unbridled sql glory:

```
SET @prevLong=-1.0000;
SET @prevLat=-1.0000;
SET @currDist=1.0000;
select id, diff from (
select id,
@prevLat prev_lat,
@currDist:= 6371 * 2 * (atan2(sqrt(sin(radians(@prevLat - lat)/2)
                       * sin(radians(@prevLat - lat)/2)
                       + cos(radians(lat))
                       * cos(radians(@prevLat))
                       * sin(radians(@prevLong - longi)/2)
                       * sin(radians(@prevLong - longi)/2))
                  ,sqrt(1-(sin(radians(@prevLat - lat)/2)
                           * sin(radians(@prevLat - lat)/2)
                           + cos(radians(lat))
                           * cos(radians(@prevLat))
                           * sin(radians(@prevLong
                                         - longi)/2)
                           * sin(radians(@prevLong - longi)/2))))) diff,
@prevLong prevLong,
case when @currdist > 5 then @prevLat:=lat  else null end  curr_lat,
case when @currDist > 5 then @prevLong:= longi  else null end  curr_long

  from latLong
order by id asc
) a where diff > 5
```

SQLFiddle to prove that magic is real:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e4fe/19

**Edit**
In Codeigniter you can use variables like the following:

```
$this->db->query("SET @prevLong=-1.0000");
$this->db->query("SET @prevLat=-1.0000");
$this->db->query("SET @prevDist=-1.0000");
```

Then issue your query as normal

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT ...");
```

Comment: this query returns the wrong result because it will just give you a list of entries where the distance between consecutive rows will be greater than 5, not considering entry #1 and it doesn't use the last found ID for the next  comparison

Comment: @ Philip your result returns "3 to 4" then "6 to 7" where i should to something like "1 to 3" then "3 to 4" then "4 to 6" then "6 to 7" for your sample data

Comment: Fixed, didn't realize that was the requirement on the first go! very simple fix.

Comment: this answer is faster than the stored procedure but there is also a shorter formular to calc the distance
6371 * acos( cos(radians( prevLat )) * cos(radians( lat)) * cos(radians( prevLong ) - radians( longi)) + sin(radians( prevLat )) * sin(radians( lat)))

Comment: Thanks for that Markus, I can update this answer once I test that... starting to wonder what it will take for @Rajendra Khabiya to accept an answer though :P

Comment: @PhilipDevine I tried it but not working with WHERE clause ?? Also do we have to pass SET @prevLong=-1.0000; SET @prevLat=-1.0000; SET @currDist=1.0000; ?? it also create problem in codeigniter (PHP framework) .. Please suggest and i will accept your answer.. Thanks !

Comment: Added how to use variables in code igniter for you.  If it still causes issues let me know, hard to mock up code igniter projects.

Comment: I'd have plus one'd this answer if it was ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: @PhilipDevine Thanks a lot... You are a saver man.. keep it up... thanks a lot...

Comment: @Rob I could do it in any other language with window functions, but unfortunately MySql doesn't have them out of the box.

Comment: @PhilipDevine my apologies, I misunderstood the original question that he wanted all sets of points with n distance, rather than just the ones n distance from the row above.  That's an uglier thing to accomplish with ANSI standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to calculate the distance from Lat Lon and then check if the result is greater than 5km. Problem with your sample data is, that the calculated distances are within **meters**, so you won't get any result from that. I guess you have a few more locations to check in your table.

try

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.Latitude, a.Longitude, CONCAT(a.ID,"-",b.ID) as 'FromTo',
    6371 * acos( 
                  cos(radians( b.Latitude ))
                * cos(radians( a.Latitude ))
                * cos(radians( b.Longitude ) - radians( a.Longitude ))
                + sin(radians( b.Latitude )) 
                * sin(radians( a.Latitude ))) as distance 
FROM new_table a INNER JOIN new_table b ON a.id <> b.id
HAVING distance >= 0.001
ORDER BY id, distance;
```

I set the having clause to greater than a meter `HAVING distance >= 0.001`. if you want to check for km adjust accordingly!

**EDIT**

it is not the fastes solution you might have to tweak it a little bit but the procedure would look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `calcDistWithin`(IN dist double)
BEGIN

declare maxTempID int;
declare maxTblID int;
declare breakLoop boolean;
SET breakLoop = FALSE;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (ID int, Latitude double, Longitude double, distance double, toID varchar(10));
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpOUT;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpOUT (ID int, Latitude double, Longitude double, distance double, toID varchar(10));

INSERT INTO tmp select ID, Latitude, Longitude, 0, "---"  from new_table limit 1;
INSERT INTO tmpOUT select ID, Latitude, Longitude, 0, "---"  from new_table limit 1;

SELECT ID INTO maxTblID FROM new_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT ID into maxTempID FROM tmp ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;

WHILE breakLoop = FALSE DO

    IF EXISTS (SELECT
                6371 * acos( 
                  cos(radians( b.Latitude ))
                * cos(radians( a.Latitude ))
                * cos(radians( b.Longitude ) - radians( a.Longitude ))
                + sin(radians( b.Latitude )) 
                * sin(radians( a.Latitude ))) as distance
               FROM tmp a INNER JOIN new_table b 
               WHERE a.ID < b.ID AND a.ID = maxTempID
               HAVING distance >= dist
               LIMIT 1) THEN

        INSERT INTO tmpOUT SELECT
            b.ID, b.Latitude, b.Longitude,
            6371 * acos( 
                  cos(radians( b.Latitude ))
                * cos(radians( a.Latitude ))
                * cos(radians( b.Longitude ) - radians( a.Longitude ))
                + sin(radians( b.Latitude )) 
                * sin(radians( a.Latitude ))) as distance,
            a.ID
        FROM tmp a INNER JOIN new_table b 
        WHERE a.ID < b.ID AND a.ID = maxTempID
        HAVING distance >= dist
        ORDER BY a.ID, b.ID, distance
        LIMIT 1;

        INSERT INTO tmp SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude, distance, toID FROM tmpOUT ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
        SELECT ID into maxTempID FROM tmpOUT order by ID DESC LIMIT 1;

    ELSE

        SET breakLoop = TRUE;

    END IF;

END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM tmpOUT;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

to call it just use

```
CALL calcDistWithin(5.00)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. yes you are right the distance in sample data is just of few meters as i have give it just as example.. I will check your query and let you know whether it will work or not.. Thanks Again !

Comment: Sorry But it not give what exactly i needed. You had compared each existing records with all remaining record and calculate distance. but what i need is to calculate distance from last selected value...
For Ex. Start from Record 1. distance of 1 is compared with record 2 it is < 5km, compared with record 3 also < 5km ,when compared with 4 its distance is > 5km so we keep it in list THAN NEXT RECORD WILL BE COMPARED WITH RECORD 4. so distance of 4 will be compared with 5 and if  record 5 have distance > 5km from 4 next comparison is done with record 5 as reference.

Comment: in that case you need to write a procedure to do that, I, at the moment cannot think of a way to query that in a single query

Comment: Can you please help me with procedure code which provide such result?

Comment: markus Thanks for the help but @Philip Devine answer above was more appropriate. Thanks Again !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want a pure sql solution or not.
I can only give a solution with other language.
I am assume to use id to determine the nearest node.

```
 List locat= new List(); 
  last = getTheLastRecord();
  locat.add(last);
  count = getTheCountOfRecord();
  for(int i=1;i<count;i++){//i = 1 because last record already read.
   Record r = getRecord(i);
   if(compareDistance(r,last)>5000){
     locat.add(r);
     last = r;
   }
 }
```

// finally the list of locat will contain every location you want.